# dynamic URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, seo

I want to rewrite the dynamic URL `https://example.page/detail-view/?mediaId=2316` and get the SEO-frendly URL `https://example.page/detail-view/2316` instead. How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are `detail-view` and `mediaid`? Please add this information to the question.

Comment: detail-view is the name of the page and mediaId is a parameter with the post-ID

Answer (score 0):

You might use following in that case

- It's okay to keep http://example.com/key_name/key_value simply by passing in your template using
  *function add_query_arg( 'key', 'value', 'http://example.com' );*
- *get_query_var('key_name')*
  to fetch the Value of Query parameters in your template file instead of using
  *$_GET['key_name']* .